# Jquery mobile chained popup dynamic positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery-mobile popup `#graphic-menu` activated by an onClick event (`getPosition()` is in another included script, and works as expected):

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="gm-btn" onclick="showGM(getPosition(this));">Graphic menu</a>
```

CSS

```
function showGM(pos){
    $("#menu-buttons").popup("close");  
    $("#menu-buttons").bind({
        popupafterclose: function(event, ui){  
            $("#graphic-menu").popup("open", {x:pos.x, y:pos.y});
        }
    });                        
}
```

The catch is that `#gm-btn` is itself part of a parent popup `#menu-buttons` that:

- is called to appear several times
- appears at different locations (it's a dragable element)

`showGM(pos)` uses the position of the `#gm-btn` when the parent popup first appears, and doesn't change for subsequent child popups when reclicked.

How can I get `showGM(getPosition(this))` to correctly recalculate the position of `#gm-btn` when called (or, more likely, what have I screwed up in my code)?

Edit: at the moment, I'm making things work by storing the position in a variable with global scope (since there's only ever one `#menu-buttons` active), and passing that to `#graphic-menu` so it knows where to open. I think this probably isn't good programming practice, so if someone has a better suggestion I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Hard to understand the operational logic here without a full example. Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure, here's the idea: click the link to get #popup1, click the button in #popup1 to get #popup2, and hope the `data-position-to` attribute means that all the popups are at the "calling object's" position. I don't find jsfiddle works very well with jquery mobile though... https://jsfiddle.net/4gjdp4te/

Comment: I added an answer and then edited it with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4gjdp4te/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the API (http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/), they say:

> **Note:** Chaining of popups not allowed: "The framework does not currently support chaining of popups so it's not possible to embed a
>   link from one popup to another popup. All links with a
>   `data-rel="popup"` inside a popup will not do anything at all."
>
> A workaround to get chained popups working is the use of a timeout for
>   example in the `popupafterclose` event bound to the invoking popup. In
>   the following example, when the first popup is closed, the second will
>   be opened by a delayed call to the open method:
>
> ```
> $( document ).on( "pageinit", function() {
>     $( ".popupParent" ).on({
>         popupafterclose: function() {
>             setTimeout(function() { $( ".popupChild" ).popup( "open" ) }, 100 );
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```

In regards to jsFiddle, it works good for this type of testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4gjdp4te/7/ You had not set the JQuery library, so I set it to 2.1.3, and retained your JQM 1.4.5 link.

My attempt so far has not yielded the results you want, but you can at least see what direction to take. I plan to keep working on it and will update my answer.

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a id="anchor1" href="#pop-1" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop">Basic Popup</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="pop-1" data-position-to="#anchor1">
      <p>This is a basic popup.</p>
      <button id="firstbutton" data-rel="popup">Button to open 2nd popup</button>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="pop-2">
      <p>This is another basic popup.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var buttonClick = false;

$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
  $("#pop-1").on({
    popupafterclose: function () {
      if (buttonClick) {
        console.log("Opening 2nd Popup.");
        setTimeout(function () {
          $("#pop-2").popup("open", {
            positionTo: "#pop-1"
          })
        }, 100);
        buttonClick = false;
      } else {
        console.log(buttonClick);
      }
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#firstbutton").click(function () {
    buttonClick = true;
    console.log("First Button clicked");
    $("#pop-1").popup("close");
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

I got the code you need: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4gjdp4te/8/

**JQUERY**

```
var buttonClick = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#pop-1").popup({
    afterclose: function(){
      if (buttonClick) {
        console.log("Opening 2nd Popup.");
        setTimeout(function () {
          $("#pop-2").popup("open", {
            positionTo: "#pop-1"
          })
        }, 100);
        buttonClick = false;
      } else {
        console.log(buttonClick);
      }
    }
  });
  $("#firstbutton").click(function () {
    buttonClick = true;
    console.log("First Button clicked");
    $("#pop-1").popup("close");
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh, thanks so much! The way you have embedded the the DOM query for  $("#pop-2") into the popup() function has caused it to be able to find its position without having to store it as a global variable. Very clever! And sorry about the jquery missing; I was playing with the URIs (changed from the official CDN to the google one) and accidentally deleted it.